# Dealing with Chrome Android auto fullscreen on rotate to landscape feature

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

Chrome 61 for Android added a feature that automatically expands a video to fullscreen when video is playing and user rotates the device to a landscape mode.
Before v61, option was hiding behind the flag `chrome://flags#video-rotate-to-fullscreen`

Is there any way to control which element is expanded? As we're having a custom wrapper with controls around jwplayer, but when Chrome sends it to a new magic fullscreen, our controls are not visible.

Comment: PornHub have same issue(

Comment: any one find the issues?